# Flex/AS3 easy (I hope) drag and drop question - prevent dragging to other controls

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex3

I searched but couldn't find my answer, I'm sure it's easy for anyone with a little experience. I have multiple datagrids on a page, each one I want sortable with drag and drop, but I don't want items drug from one control to the other. How can I prevent a user from dragging an item out of a conrol. I would prefer to have it just stop moving with the mouse, but I am prepared to just completely cancel out of the dragging if need be.
I was trying to do something like this

```
dragExit="dragEvent.CANCEL"
```

This is obviously wrong, but I can't find the correct way to do it.

Thanks in advance.
~Mike

Comment: For clarification you want to prohibit dragging from a datagrid on a per-item basis? Or on a specific datagrid as a whole?

Comment: I just don't want them to drag something beyond the borders of the source datagrid. I want them to drag and drop within the datagrid to their hearts desire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you have an app with multiple drag/drop datagrids, and you only want items dragged within a datagrid, and not from 1 to the other, is how I understand this.

What you need to do is create a custom `dragDrop` event handler for each datagrid which has the following command: `event.preventDefault()`.  This in effect will stop a datagrid from receiving items from another .

This does not prohibit the dragging an item outside its host's borders, but it will prohibit the item being dropped into a different datagrid.

HTH.